# Chrome browser crashing

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, v8

When I am loading 5mb JSON data the chrome uses 54% of memory Still more than 30 % is available.Why the chrome is not able to utilize the free space available.The V8 can support 1gb data in standalone so the browser have to be more efficient.Why is it crashing at low data size ??

The steps that I followed  is as given

1)Copy the Index .html and flare.json file from the following link- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

2)Add more data to the flare.json file and make it to 5mb

3)run the index.html file

Unresponsive script Error !!

Comment: Chrome is becoming unresponsive because the d3.js is taking time to process the 5mb of data and the browser UI thread becomes unresponsive cause of that. If it's 5Mb then the number of objects d3.js need to iterate and construct are going to be very high. One thing you do to avoid this is do lazy evaluation using settimeout/setInterval

Comment: I would try lazy loading, the parsing might crash the browser. Here is another discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937516/maximum-json-size-for-response-to-the-browser

Comment: I have successfully visualized 11 mb data using the  same chart  on a chromium interface using Node web kit.If the problem is with the visualizer,How was I able to do it ??@mohamedrias